# Firestore request.time. toMillis() not returning a number in milisec

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried everything but I can't get this security rule to work.
 I run 'get' in Simulator for path '`posts/post-1-id`', where `resource.data.time` is time in milisce from epoch 1528316285901, which is a number.

Basically I tried all the configurations `<, >, !=, ==, <=, >=` just to try pass the security rule using `request.time` but I will alway get 'Simulated data access denied'.

How to compare data from `resource.data.time` in milisec to request.time ?
Or how to just compare date of creation of document to request.time?

```
match /posts/{id} {
      allow read: if request.time.toMillis() > resource.data.time;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be a bug with the simulator. I'm am having the same issue from the simulator and I see the error `Property time is undefined on object`. You rules look like they should work though.

Note that testing your rules without the simulator is very difficult as it can take up to 10 minutes to publish new rules and during that 10 minutes requests may randomly be handled by your new or old rules.

Comment: Thanks! It was a firestore security rulest simulator bug.